# Compute LatLngBounds from user location

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm using Google Maps JavaScript API v3, and I'm using the Places API to return autocomplete results. I want to bound the results returned from `Autocomplete` to the city the user is in, if I have their location.

I know that if I actually geocode a location, like "Houston, TX, USA", part of the response from the Google Maps API will contain a `LatLngBounds` that I can use as the bounds from something like `Autocomplete`. However, because I'm getting the user's location through the browser, all I have is a set of latitude and longitude coordinates. The most straight-forward solution is to reverse geocode the user's location to get their approximate region, and then geocode that region to get the `LatLngBounds`. However, that seems highly inefficient. Is there a more efficient way to achieve this without this back and forth geocoding?

Comment: The place response contains a viewport/bounds for the result returned, but not for any other of its address components.

Comment: Hi Chris I saw that you commented on an answer of mine (thanks for the positive comment), then I saw this question of yours and thought it looked a little strange because I can get the bounds from autocomplete with the code `place.geometry.viewport.getSouthWest().lat().toFixed(6);` (and so on for the 3 other coordinates that make the boundary). Is this what you were looking for?

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately, I'm looking to set the bounds on `Autocomplete` based on the user's location from the JavaScript Geolocation API (builtin, not Google), not get the bounds from an already setup `Autocomplete`. I did find somewhat of a solution, which I'll go ahead and post here.

Comment: ok now I get you, I think..are you talking about the `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition`? If so then I have a solution for getting the boundary that's better than your posted solution. It grabs `results[0].geometry.viewport.getSouthWest().lat().toFixed(6);` from the google maps geocoder and is very fast. If you're interested, comment and include my name so I get a notification.

Answer (score 0):

I found out that you can get the bounds from a `Circle` object, even without actually drawing it on a map. You just create a new `Circle` centered on the user's location, with a radius of how many meters out you want the bounds to be. For example, this creates a circle with a 25 mile (40,233.6 meters) radius:

```
var circle = new google.maps.Circle({ radius: 40233.6, center: userLatLng });
```

Then, you just call `getBounds`:

```
autocomplete.setBounds(circle.getBounds());
```

It's not *exactly* what I was looking for, but it works well enough.